# how to force Qt mainWindow to wait for some changes

Tags: c++, qt

I am designing UI for my opencv application and I'm new in Qt.

I have a **QString** in my Qt code that is a licence plate. and it can be change when a car arrive to our camera, but we don't know when it change.

and when car arrive we need to show it's plate on a QTableView on MainWindow.

how can I handle it in Qt?

I make my code simple here:

> mainWindow.h

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

    .
    .
    .

    public slots:
        void set_plate(QString p);

    signals:
        void plate_changed(QString newPlate);

    private:
        Ui::MainWindow *ui;
        QString plate;

};
```

> mainWindow.cpp

```
    void MainWindow::set_plate(QString newPlate)
    {
        if(plate != newPlate){
            plate = newPlate;
            emit plate_changed(newPlate);
        }
    }

    MainWindow::MainWindow(QString p, QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow),
    plate(p)
    {
    .
    .
    .
    QTableWidgetItem* item2;
    item2 = new QTableWidgetItem(plate);
    ui->table->setItem(table->rowCount() - 1, 0, item2);
}
```

> main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QString plate;
    .
    .
    .
    //some changes on plate

    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w(plate);
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

thanks

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking...is your MainWindow supposed to show the plate? And reflect change if any? The code you sent does not show that MainWindow is displaying the plate string or not...

Comment: you are right. I try to edit it for make my problem clear @jpo38

Answer (score 0):

When you detect a car, send a signal to your instance. Connect your emitted signal to your slot and that's all.

https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_for_Beginners#Creating_custom_signals_and_slots

Comment: can you tell me how can i use "connect" in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Let's begin with a paraphrase of the code for `main` that you've posted

```
void someChangesOnPlate(QString &);
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QString plate;
    someChangesOnPlate(plate);
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w(plate);
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

It seems that `someChangesOnPlate` would be a plate detection code that runs continuously in a loop, taking images from the camera, detecting plates, and extracting the plate numbers.

The main mistake in your approach is: while the plate detection code is running, the application window isn't shown yet - the code *after* `someChangesOnPlate` hasn't executed yet! The execution is within `someChangesOnPlate`, after all.

What you need to do, instead, is to run `someChangesOnPlate` in a separate thread, and to have that thread invoke the main window's `newPlate` method in a thread-safe fashion. Given C++11, this is a very straightforward change:

```
void someChangesOnPlate(MainWindow *);
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w(plate);
    w.show();
    std::thread thread(someChangesOnPlate, &w);
    int rc = a.exec();
    thread.join(); // wait for the thread to finish
    return rc;
}
```

Within the `someChangesOnPlate` code, the thread-safe call to `newPlate` is done as follows:

```
void someChangesOnPlate(MainWindow * w) {
  while (...) {
    // process camera images
    ...
    QString plate = ....;
    ...
    QMetaObject::invoke(w, "newPlate", Qt::QueuedConnection, Q_ARG(QString, plate));
    ...
  }
}
```

Finally, I understand that you want a *new* item to be added to the table whenever a new plate is indicated. Here's how to do it:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
  Q_OBJECT
  Ui::MainWindow ui; // no need for it to be a pointer
  QString m_lastPlate;
public:
  MainWindow(QWidget * parent = 0) : QMainWindow(parent) {
    ui.setupUi(this);
  }
  Q_SLOT void newPlate(const QString & plate) {
    if (plate == m_lastPlate) return;
    m_lastPlate = plate;
    auto item = new QTableWidgetItem(plate);
    ui->table->setItem(table->rowCount() - 1, 0, item);
  }
}
```